# Как работает команда 'x' в GNU GDB

Tags: linux, c, gdb, x86-64

Доброго времени суток. Я не совсем представлял как назвать тему, измените её название исходя из контекста, если это возможно.

В **gdb** есть команда 'exemine', сокращенно 'x'. Она позволяет просматримвать данные в памяти, начиная с какого-то адреса **n** двигаясь вперёд, в направлении старших адресов. Каждая программа имеет сегмент кучу и стек, которые растут друг другу на встречу (стек от старших адресов к младшим, а куча наоборот). Также в процессоре есть регистр esp (rsp), которые указывает на **вершину стека**.

Теперь главное: почему если ввести команду 'x/12xw $rsp', то команда показывает данные, что есть в стеке. ESP указывает на вершину, exemine должен двигаться от этой вершины вперёд, то есть выше стека. Как так происходит: команда 'x' "подстраивается" или я что-то не правильно понял?

Если ввести обычный адрес, то exemine двигается вперёд, но ведь $rsp это тоже по сути адрес (по моему этот макрос gdb заменит на адрес вершины стека). Я плохо объяснил наверное. Помогите мне осилить, если кто-то осилил мое объяснение.

Comment: У меня `uname -a ; cat /etc/issue; gdb --version
Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-91-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 17:00:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1` вообще-то **х** всегда  движется в одну сторону (увеличения адресов) `(gdb) x/xw 0x004009f8
0x4009f8 <main+1064>: 0x8bde8948
(gdb) x
0x4009fc <main+1068>: 0xc6834816
(gdb) x
0x400a00 <main+1072>: 0xff828d04
(gdb)` и `(gdb) x/xw $rsp
0x7fffffffd148: 0x004009f8
(gdb) x
0x7fffffffd14c: 0x00000000
(gdb) x 
0x7fffffffd150: 0x00000000`

Comment: я о том же. Он всегда увеличивает адреса. Но адрес вершины стека некуда увеличивать, все его значения ниже вершины либо на ней, а выходит что он нормально выводит значения, будто уменшает адреса (нет). Я запутался и не могу это понять, осмыслить.

Comment: Стек (обычно) растет в сторону меньших адресов, следовательно наши данные как раз находятся в адресах больших, чем у вершины. Все правильно. Как ведет себя gdb **x** на машинах, где стек наоборот, растет в сторону старших адресов -- не знаю, ни разу не смотрел.

Answer (score 3):

> (gdb) help x
>
> Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
>
> ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
>
> FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.

Судя по описанию комманды . Вы указываете начальный адрес в памяти и размер одного элемента (байт, два байта и т.д.) и колличество элементов для отображения. Поэтому, можно сазать "двигаемся в перед по памяти".

НО очень важный момент какой парядок байт в памяти.

Для пример у вас есть переменая `unsigned short x = 0x55aa;`
в отладчике можно посмотреть ее

```
(gdb) p x
$2 = 21930
```

но можно посмотреть ее адрес

```
(gdb) p &x
$3 = (unsigned short *) 0x7fffffffe10c
```

и если мы посмотрим уже память то порядок байт заметен.

```
(gdb) x/1hx  &x
0x7fffffffe10c: 0x55aa
(gdb) x/2bx  &x
0x7fffffffe10c: 0xaa    0x55
```